# Opencart: Product Name Print Several times, How to fix.?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, opencart

i had added the following Opencart module for my order report list...
http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=3597&filter_search=order%20list%20filter%20model&page=4

I have problems with the column "Products". If there are more than one option the products name prints several times. So if I got a product with three options the product name prints three times. Is there any way to fix this problem?

i want print product name and model number only once, any idea.?

**i will attach the results what i got now...**
[image]

**this is my sql query...**

```
public function getOrders($data = array()) { 
$sql = "select o.order_id,o.email,o.telephone,CONCAT(o.shipping_address_1, ' ', o.shipping_address_2) AS address,CONCAT(o.firstname, ' ', o.lastname) AS customer,o.payment_zone AS state,o.payment_address_2 AS block, o.payment_address_1 AS address,o.payment_postcode AS postcode,(SELECT os.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status os WHERE os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id AND os.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS  status,o.payment_city AS city,GROUP_CONCAT(pd.name) AS pdtname,GROUP_CONCAT(op.model) AS model,o.date_added,sum(op.quantity) AS quantity,GROUP_CONCAT(opt.value ) AS options, GROUP_CONCAT(opt.order_product_id )  AS ordprdid,GROUP_CONCAT(op.order_product_id )  AS optprdid, GROUP_CONCAT(op.quantity) AS opquantity from `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product op ON (op.order_id = o.order_id)  LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (pd.product_id = op.product_id and pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order_option opt ON (opt.order_product_id = op.order_product_id) ";
```

Product Name = `GROUP_CONCAT(pd.name) AS pdtname,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `DISTINCT`

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pd.name)
```

Comment: Please also inform the author of the modification of the bug so they can fix it.